# how to insert facebook page link manually in header php?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

[image: dashboard]

I have a problem editing facebook link in header.php because the plugins in the dashboard are not around and  settings is disabled also..this is wordpress version 3.7.4..the image below is the navigation..My friend want me to add facebook page but the one who make his site disable some important features..and this is not a wordpress hosted site that is in wordpress.com..

[image: navigation]

Now I want to link the facebook icon to facebook page that i made..and i do it manually through the header.php of the theme Inovado...i go to public_html/wp-content/themes/inovado..then header.php..

and this is the header php code

```
<?php if($data['social_facebook'] != "") { ?>
                            <li class="social-facebook"><a href="<?php echo $data['social_facebook']; ?>" target="_blank" title="<?php _e( 'Facebook', 'minti' ) ?>"><?php _e( 'Facebook', 'minti' ) ?></a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
```

my facebook url is https://www.facebook.com/pages/Pools101/1553059094928726
I have tried inserting this one in the

Answer (score 0):

ok i already solve my problem.. i only change

```
echo $data['social_facebook'];
```

to

```
echo esc_url('http://www.facebook.com');
```

this problem is solved